# Monospaced editable text in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, controls

I had some little experience in coding, but I am absolute beginner in C#. In my program I want to make the text visible in form, sort of like in HxD program. I don't want it to be standard editable text, but a monospaced text which can be selected, and if selected there would be yellowish (but with no border) background in back of it, I have no idea how to do this, if even possible with standard controls. How can I implement this? Do I need to use some external library? I want also to mention that I want spaces between characters and lines to be configurable.

I am using Visual Studio C# 2015.

Here is mock-up:

[image]

Comment: Read-only `TextBox`/textedit control with word-wrapping and the font set to a monospaced font. Are you looking at WPF or winforms? IIRC you might possibly have trouble setting the highlight color in winforms.

Comment: I am using standard Windows Forms, but I might switch to WPF if it is neccessary and relatively easy.

Comment: There is also blinking symbol I don't want.

Comment: The WPF learning curve is very much steeper than winforms. The payoff is proportional, when you finally get there. If you feel like a challenge, and/or if a non-windows-default highlight color is an absolute requirement, go with WPF.

Comment: Ah, I will definitely try it, I think it will be the best choice, as I just started and it is probably better to go with newer features than more legacy ones.

Comment: Hm, here's another thing: Wrapping is usually done by word, not by character. That part may actually be the biggest challenge here.

Comment: Further to that last comment: When you run into that problem, a kludge might be to insert a zero-width space between each character, and replace spaces with non-breaking spaces: `s = String.Join("\x200B", s.Replace(" ", "\x00a0"));`

Answer (score 1):

I've done similar before using a RichTextBox that wasn't editable by users.  It has more functions for manipulating just part of the string than TextBox does.